# Tensorflow: Track the values a tensor takes

Tags: tensorflow

Through a forward pass in my network I wanted to log the values a particular tf.variable takes. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Look into [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard). It largely depends on what you're doing with the variable. If it's just a scalar variable you can plot it. To get exact values, pass the tensor reference to your `session.run()` and get the full output.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to log or debug data in TensorFlow.

The simplest is to run it in a session, or eval. e.g.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

v = tf.Variable([0.0])
# you can do other graph things here.

print sess.run(v)
# alternatively
print v.eval()
```

This often isn't possible, so another approach is to put tf.Print ops in your graph. Here's how you would print the variable whenever it's used.

```
import tensorflow as tf

v = tf.Variable([0.0], name="the_var")
v = tf.Print(v, [v], "the_var = ")

# ... do things with 'v' as if it was the variable op
```

The [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) op will only print the first few entries if you have a large tensor, so check the docs for the `summarize` and `first_n` parameters to control how much is logged.

You can use TensorBoard to log summaries of variables during graph execution too. If you're not already using it, you should [check it out](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard), many of the higher-level APIs within TensorFlow already log a lot of information about the model variables during execution to TensorBoard. To perform your own logging in TensorBoard, use something like [tf.summary.scalar](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar) or [tf.summary.histogram](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/histogram).

```
v = tf.Variable([0.0])
# this will log to the 'distributions' tab in tensorboard too
tf.summary.scalar(v)
tf.summary.histogram(v)
```

Check out the docs for details on how to save these summaries to disk during execution: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard.

And lastly, there's a debugger available for TensorFlow, [tfdbg](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/tfdbg), you can use to step through graph execution and dump the contents of tensors.

Answer (score 0):

you can debug for values at each step the tensorflow variable takes.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I'd do this?